# Android select another edit text onKeyListener

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a table layout that I dynamically insert a couple of extra rows into. I set the `android:imeOptions="actionNext"`. My listener code is below:

```
textKind.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (keyCode == event.KEYCODE_ENTER){
                ((EditText)findViewById(5+v.getId())).requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

I want to have a specific edit text request focus if I tap the `Next` button on the soft keyboard. The code below shows how I assign my id's:

```
textKind.setId(columnNumberCount);
textVariety.setId(columnNumberCount+5);
textCode.setId(columnNumberCount+10);
textArea.setId(columnNumberCount+15);
textPathogen.setId(columnNumberCount+20);
textDegree.setId(columnNumberCount+25);
textSample.setId(columnNumberCount+30);
textCrop.setId(columnNumberCount+35);
textGeneral.setId(columnNumberCount+40);

this.columnNumber++;
```

I have set it up so that I can add a max of four columns. That is why I set the id as the  `count + 5`. At the moment the next button navigates the cursor right and not down (with all columns added). Does anyone have suggestions? Thanks

**Edit**

I changed my code to detect the enter button correctly:

```
textKind.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_NEXT){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter pressed", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                ((EditText)findViewById(5+v.getId())).requestFocus();
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

The focus still doesn't go to the next edit text.

**Edit - A graphical description of my issue**

[image]

At the moment the cursor moves to the edit text on the right. I want the cursor to move down and not right.

Comment: please explain the problem..

Comment: @Droid Sure, the cursor moves to the next column edit text and not down to the next edit text in the currently selected column.

Comment: this is because you have added the keyListener to the textkind EditText only

Comment: @Droid I am listening for a key press on my textKind so that I can navigate to the next editText. Just so that I can see if this could work. Adding a key listener to the next editText would not make a difference because I am using .requestfocus() which does not need a keyListener to work. Thanx for the suggestion though, but that is not the problem

Comment: could you explain it with the graphic representation

Comment: @Droid Sure, I will add a pic now

Comment: @Droid There, I have added a image.

Comment: onkey listener y dont u just set request focus to desired edittext like editText2.requestFocus();

Comment: provide id of the edittext which is below

Comment: @AvinashKumarPankaj I set an id for each edit text as shown in the code to get the text value when I reference it. If I had to say textVariety.requestFocus(), I would only request focus on the edit text in the last column added.

Comment: @Droid I am providing the id of the edit text below, but the focus still moves to the right instead of down.

Comment: what is the initial value of columnNumberCount?

Comment: @Droid it is 0, I just increment it each time I add a column

Comment: textVariety id will be 5.. m i right?

Comment: @Droid Yes you are right

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39476/discussion-between-droid-and-lunchbox)